# Facebook share page dialog image size

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I trying to implement a page share function to my website by following [this fb guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/). I've added the  tags just like fb developers site requires but I'm struggling with the image size. The image is out of bounds (see image below) in the share dialog. I'm uploading [this image](https://storage.googleapis.com/cvcentrs-logos/CVcentrs_logo_fb_share_size.png) that is 600x202px. I tried uploading the same image with 1200x404px and adding the meta `og:image:widht/ height` values but still the image in the share dialog is going out of bounds. I cant figure out what is causing this and how to fit the image in to the share dialog. Any ideas?

**This is the result of the share**
[image]

**The actual image**

[image]

**html**

```
    <head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://cvcentrs-staging.herokuapp.com{{ request.path }}"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{ object.title }}"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/cvcentrs-logos/CVcentrs_logo_fb_share_size.png"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
</head>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images: _"Non-open Graph Stories images appear in a rectangular format. You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio, such as 600x314px."_

Comment: You are citing the section that relates to Images for Gaming Apps. This share dialog image is not related to gaming apps

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that this is the recommended aspect ratio, has been for years. https://buffer.com/library/ideal-image-sizes-social-media-posts/